# Select a single list item in bootstrap-multiselect dropdown using List<SelectListItem>

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using a twitter bootstrap-multiselect dropdown in my MVC4 Razor view

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.States, Model.States, new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddlState", placeholder = "Select State" })
```

I am using it as a single select drop down i.e. without 'multiple' property

```
$('#ddlState').multiselect({
            enableFiltering: true,
            nonSelectedText: 'Select State',
            enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
            maxHeight: 200
  });
```

I am populating the above drop down using a `SelectListItem` 
in the following way.

```
public List<SelectListItem> BindStates()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = (DataSet)Session["SDMVTMasterDropDownData"];
            List<SelectListItem> states = new List<SelectListItem>();
            states = (from DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows
                      select new SelectListItem()
                   {
                       Text = (dr["StateName"]).ToString(),
                       Value = dr["StateId"].ToString(),
                       Selected = (bool)dr["SelectedStatus"],
                   }).ToList();
            return states;
        }
```

This is my dataset for the above list

```
StateId      StateName      SelectedStatus
  1        ANDHRA PRADESH        1
  2        BIHAR                 0
  3        CHANDIGARH            0
```

But the problem is that even though i set the `Selected` property to true, the dropdown doesnt make the respective list item selected.

Instead the first item in the list is selected by default.

While going through the internet i have observed that using the property `selected='selected'` can be used to set the selected option.

Like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#example-single-selected').multiselect();
</script>

<select id="example-single-selected">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="6">Option 6</option>
</select>
```

But this is the static way , how do achieve this while populating the list from controller?

Here is the link for the reference doc for this bootstrap-multiselect dropdown http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-multiple

Comment: (1) You cannot use the same name for the property your binding to and the `SelectList` (2) If you wanting a multiple `<select>`, use `ListBoxFor()`, not `DropDownListFor()` (3) Setting the `Selected` value is ignored when you bind to a model - its the value of the property which determines what is selected

Comment: @StephenMuecke If you dont mind, can you please elaborate? i did not get your point

Comment: @i dont want to use a multiple select dropdown, i need only single select , but since in all the remaining pages of my application i have used the bootstrap-multiselect control, i am using the same control to maintain uniformity in the Look & Feel

Comment: Your model needs a property `int SelectedState` to bind to, and a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StateList` for the options. Then set `model.SelectedState = 3;` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view and the 2nd option (`BIHAR`) will be selected (and delete the unnecessary `SelectListItem.Selected` value) The view is then `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedState, Model.StatesList, ... )`